# Getter evaluation in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following getter:

```
public DateTime LastWeek {    
  get { return this.FirstWeek.AddDays(7 *this.WeeksCount); } 
}
```

and following query

```
var query = from o in dataContext.Operations 
            where o.Date <= param.LastWeek && o.Date >= param.FirstWeek;
```

Will LastWeek getter get evaluated prior to query execution and will be its value passed there or will it be translated to something like DATEADD(... - so its logic will be transferred to query?

It is easy to try by using both approaches, the one above, or taking lastWeek value to extra variable:

```
var lastWeek = param.LastWeek;
```

But we would have to check every query - is there any global rule which can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

```
string queryText = (from o in dataContext.Operations 
            where o.Date <= param.LastWeek && o.Date >= param.FirstWeek).ToString();
```

and you will see what sql query will be build.

Answer (score 0):

The logic inside the `LastWeek` get implementation will not be transferred to SQL. But I am confident they will be evaluated in C# only when the query is translated to SQL.  Put a breakpoint into the getter and see if it gets hit before the query is executed but after it is defined.

The stuff that is translated to SQL are expressions, not implementations (Linq maps a few calls to SQL such as `Contains()`, `Any()` and so on though).